# Using Java generic class in Scala throws wrong number of type arguments error

Tags: java, scala, generics, arguments

I have a generic class in Java - RequestWrapper.java

```
package com.wipro.nepc.coe.requestWrapper;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class RequestWrapper<T> implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    T requestDetails;
    String ownerIpAddress;

    public RequestWrapper(T requestDetails, String ownerIpAddress) {
        this.requestDetails = requestDetails;
        this.ownerIpAddress = ownerIpAddress;
    }

    public T getRequestDetails() {
        return requestDetails;
    }

    public void setRequestDetails(T requestDetails) {
        this.requestDetails = requestDetails;
    }

    public String getOwnerIpAddress() {
        return ownerIpAddress;
    }

    public void setOwnerIpAddress(String ownerIpAddress) {
        this.ownerIpAddress = ownerIpAddress;
    }

}
```

I am able to create an object of RequestWrapper in another Java class like this:

```
HashMap<String,Object> testMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
Object obj = new Integer(1);    
testMap.put("one",obj);

String ownerIp = "10.145.59.107";

RequestWrapper<HashMap<String, Object>> requestWrap = 
        new RequestWrapper<HashMap<String,Object>>(testMap, ownerIp);
```

I try to do the same in a Scala object:

```
import java.util.HashMap

var testMap = new HashMap[String,Object]
var obj = new Integer(1);
testMap.put("one", obj);

var ownerIp: String = "10.145.59.107"

var requestWrap = new RequestWrapper[HashMap[String,Object]](testMap,ownerIp)
```

But I get the following error:

> wrong number of type arguments for
>   com.wipro.nepc.coe.requestWrapper.RequestWrapper, should be 2

Why is this error thrown in Scala? The generic class has only one type argument, which when used in Java does not throw any error and works perfect. But in scala its asks for an extra type argument.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error was thrown only by Eclipse. The project got compiled successfully by Maven. Weird why Eclipse threw that error